# Deleting an element in array

Tags: java, arrays, element

This keeps throwing a `NullPointerException` after the if statement, do any of you have an idea why?

```
public void deleteCourse() {

    Scanner courseInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter coursename to delete");
    String deleteInput = courseInput.nextLine();
    System.out.println("check");
    int pos = this.findPosition(deleteInput);
    System.out.println(pos);
    if (pos != -1) {

        students[pos].setName(students[students.length - 1].getName());
        students[pos].setGrade(students[students.length - 1].getGrade());

    }

}

public int findPosition(String deleteInput) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {

        if (deleteInput.equals(students[i].getName())) {
            return i;
        }

    }

    return -1;

}
```

Comment: Clearly `students` or something in `students` is null. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: post the complete stack trace when you have exception; makes it easier for us to help.

Answer (score 1):

At least one of the values of the array `students` has not been set by you and is `null`. When you try to access the element that is `null` via `getName()`, you get the `NullPointerException`.

To prevent this, simply skip the elements that are `null`:

```
public int findPosition(String deleteInput) {
    if(deleteInput == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {

        if (students[i] != null && deleteInput.equals(students[i].getName())) {
            return i;
        }

    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: you are returning index i when student[i] is null.. its the opposite you want